# Multiple names for exports.help on discord .js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this command

```js
exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
    message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/509596556035358720/798747421235609632/video0_1.mov`)
}
    
exports.help = {
    name: 'didntask'
}
```

I wish for a way to make to so the exports.help, name: is more than 1 option. Let's say so the command works with both the command !didnt ask and !whoasked,

You may want to see my command handler to maybe help me so here it is too

```js
bot.on('ready', () => { //command handler
    fs.readdir('./commands', (err, files) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() == 'js');
    
        if(jsfile.length == 0) {
            return console.log("Could Not Find Any Commands!")
        }
    
        jsfile.forEach(f => {
            let props = require (`./commands/${f}`);
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just make an array of names and iterate over it. 
So, in your command:

```js
exports.help = {
    name: ['didntask', 'whoasked']
}
```

and in your command handler:

```js
jsfile.forEach(f => {
    let props = require (`./commands/${f}`);
    props.help.name.forEach(e => bot.commands.set(e, props));
});
```

Comment: where exactly do you need to place `props.help.name.forEach(e => bot.commands.set(e, props));`

Comment: @BLADEZ replace your `bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)` with it. I updated the answer.

Comment: **TypeError: props.help.name.forEach is not a function** is what is coming up for me

Comment: @BLADEZ You probably need to update all your commands to use an array rather than a string as `name`. Or you check if the given element is an array.